# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apache_beam' but its actually installed

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

OS: BigSur M1

python ver: 3.8.6
pip: 21.1.2

I am  trying to run the following code that i got from the gcp dataflow examples:

```py
import argparse
import logging
import re

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions


class WordExtractingDoFn(beam.DoFn):
"""Parse each line of input text into words."""
def process(self, element):
 """Returns an iterator over the words of this element.

 The element is a line of text.  If the line is blank, note that, too.

 Args:
   element: the element being processed

 Returns:
   The processed element.
 """
 return re.findall(r'[\w\']+', element, re.UNICODE)


def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
"""Main entry point; defines and runs the wordcount pipeline."""
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
   '--input',
   dest='input',
   default='gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt',
   help='Input file to process.')
parser.add_argument(
   '--output',
   dest='output',
   required=True,
   help='Output file to write results to.')
known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

# We use the save_main_session option because one or more DoFn's in this
# workflow rely on global context (e.g., a module imported at module level).
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session

# The pipeline will be run on exiting the with block.
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

 # Read the text file[pattern] into a PCollection.
 lines = p | 'Read' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input)

 counts = (
     lines
     | 'Split' >> (beam.ParDo(WordExtractingDoFn()).with_output_types(str))
     | 'PairWIthOne' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x, 1))
     | 'GroupAndSum' >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum))

 # Format the counts into a PCollection of strings.
 def format_result(word, count):
   return '%s: %d' % (word, count)

 output = counts | 'Format' >> beam.MapTuple(format_result)

 # Write the output using a "Write" transform that has side effects.
 # pylint: disable=expression-not-assigned
 output | 'Write' >> WriteToText(known_args.output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
run()
```

but when i try i keep getting this error and i just cant find out what the problem is:

```
 python hello.py --output
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 26, in <module>
    import apache_beam as beam
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apache_beam'
```

and this is the output from pip:

```
 pip list
Package                         Version
------------------------------- ---------
apache-beam                     2.29.0
```

I followed the tutorial from gcp with the virtual enviroment and everything. Generated the key and everything but I have been stuck on this for several hours now. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You might have installed apache-beam on an another Python interpreter. Are you using a venv to run this script on apache?

Comment: I am experiencing this similar error. I am using a venv to run my script and downgraded it to 3.7.3 from 3.9